# LUCENE: how to get all terms for a given doc by docNr without storing the data nor the TermVector (LUKE is able to show this, how?)

Tags: java, lucene

in my code example i create three document in a lucene index.
two of them not storing the field LASTNAME, but have stored termvector, one have non of them stored.
with LUKE i am able to iterate through all terms in this field (LASTNAME).
in my code example iterate through the TermFreqVectors, that works fine for document with stored TermVectors.

how can i get all this non stored Terms? how is LUKE doing that?

my original problem is, that i want to extend a big index (60GB) with nearly 100 fields with another field without re-creating the index from scratch, because with our db-setup it needs with 40 parallel computing server a couple of days.
it is very fast to read all the data from the index and just add this new field to all stored documents.

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.MockAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.RandomIndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.TermFreqVector;
import org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException;
import org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopDocs;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.util.LuceneTestCase;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class TestDocTerms extends LuceneTestCase {

public void testDocTerms() throws IOException, ParseException {
    Analyzer analyzer = new MockAnalyzer(random);

    String fieldF = "FIRSTNAME";
    String fieldL = "LASTNAME";

    // To store an index on disk, use this instead:
    Directory directory = NIOFSDirectory.open(new File("/tmp/_index_tester/"));
    RandomIndexWriter iwriter = new RandomIndexWriter(random, directory, analyzer);
    iwriter.w.setInfoStream(VERBOSE ? System.out : null);
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(newField(fieldF, "Alex", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
    doc.add(newField(fieldL, "Miller", Field.Store.NO,Field.Index.ANALYZED,Field.TermVector.YES));
    iwriter.addDocument(doc);
    doc = new Document();
    doc.add(newField(fieldF, "Chris", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
    doc.add(newField(fieldL, "Smith", Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
    iwriter.addDocument(doc);
    doc = new Document();
    doc.add(newField(fieldF, "Alex", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
    doc.add(newField(fieldL, "Beatle", Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED,Field.TermVector.YES));
    iwriter.addDocument(doc);
    iwriter.close();

    // Now search the index:
    IndexSearcher isearcher = new IndexSearcher(directory, true); // read-only=true
    QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(TEST_VERSION_CURRENT, fieldF, analyzer);
    Query query = parser.parse(fieldF + ":" + "Alex");
    TopDocs hits = isearcher.search(query, null, 2);
    assertEquals(2, hits.totalHits);
    // Iterate through the results:
    for (int i = 0; i < hits.scoreDocs.length; i++) {
        Document hitDoc = isearcher.doc(hits.scoreDocs[i].doc);
        assertEquals("Alex", hitDoc.get(fieldF));
        System.out.println("query for:" +query.toString()+ " with this results firstN:" + hitDoc.get(fieldF) + " and lastN:" + hitDoc.get(fieldL));
    }
    parser = new QueryParser(TEST_VERSION_CURRENT, fieldL, analyzer);
    query = parser.parse(fieldL + ":" + "Miller");
    hits = isearcher.search(query, null, 2);
    assertEquals(1, hits.totalHits);
    // Iterate through the results:
    for (int i = 0; i < hits.scoreDocs.length; i++) {
        Document hitDoc = isearcher.doc(hits.scoreDocs[i].doc);
        assertEquals("Alex", hitDoc.get(fieldF));
        System.out.println("query for:" + query.toString() + " with this results firstN:" +hitDoc.get(fieldF)+ " and lastN:" +hitDoc.get(fieldL));
    }
    isearcher.close();

    // examine terms
    IndexReader ireader = IndexReader.open(directory, true); // read-only=true
    int numDocs = ireader.numDocs();

    for (int i = 0; i < numDocs; i++) {
        doc = ireader.document(i);
        System.out.println("docNum:" + i + " with:" + doc.toString());
        TermFreqVector t = ireader.getTermFreqVector(i, fieldL);
        if (t != null){
            System.out.println("Field:" + fieldL + " contains terms:" + t.toString());
        }
        TermFreqVector[] termFreqVectors = ireader.getTermFreqVectors(i);
        if (termFreqVectors != null){
            for (TermFreqVector tfv : termFreqVectors){
                String[] terms = tfv.getTerms();
                String field = tfv.getField();
                System.out.println("Field:" +field+ " contains terms:" + Arrays.toString(terms));
            }
        }
    }
    ireader.close();
}


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reconstructing unstored documents is necessarily a best effort.  You can't generally reverse changes made to the value by the analyzer.

When TermVectors are not available, Luke enumerates the terms associated with the field.  This may not respect the ordering of the terms, or any formatting.  That may be neither here nor there, though.  I don't know what your `newField` method does exactly, but I suspect it's default is not `Field.TermVector.NO`.

If you want to know more of the implementation details, I would grab the Luke source code, and read `org.getopt.luke.DocReconstructor`